# Fastest way to perform calculation between two dataframe colums?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 6 million rows. The columns are:

```
['x', 'y']
```

I need to apply a simple calculation between `x` an `y`, and append it to the dataframe.

This is what I've tried:

```
'''
Calculates the height of a pressure level in feet
'''
def pressure_to_elevation(P, T = None):

    sea_level_pressure = 1013.25

    if T is not None:
        # https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/air-pressure-at-altitude

        P0 = sea_level_pressure
        g = 9.80665
        M = 0.0289644
        R0 = 8.31447

        m = (np.log(P/P0)*T) / -(g*M/R0)
        f = 3.28084 * m
        return f

    b = 0.190284
    c = 145366.45

    return (1-math.pow((P/sea_level_pressure), b)) * c


test_df['result'] = test_fd.apply(lambda row: pressure_to_elevation(row['x'], row['y']),axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, this takes a ridiculous amount of time... in fact, I've yet to see it complete.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: This will depend on your __real__ function - can you provide a definition of the real function? For your current question the fastest would be: `test_df['result'] = test_df['x'] + test_df['y']`

Comment: Using `.apply` is shorthand for iterating over the rows in the dataframe, which with 6M rows, that is going to be slow.  Depending on your needs, you can probably find a method using the built-in pandas methods / operations.

Comment: @MaxU okay, updated to include the actual function.

Comment: @pookie, could you also post a small (3-5 rows) sample data set and your desired data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def pressure_to_elevation(P, T):

    sea_level_pressure = 1013.25

    P0 = sea_level_pressure
    g = 9.80665
    M = 0.0289644
    R0 = 8.31447

    b = 0.190284
    c = 145366.45

    return np.where(T.notnull(),
                    3.28084 * ((np.log(P/P0)*T) / -(g*M/R0)),
                    (1-np.pow((P/sea_level_pressure), b)) * c)
```

Usage:

```
test_df['result'] = pressure_to_elevation(test_df['x'], test_df['y'])
```

Comment: @pookie, glad it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you break this out into separate steps and avoid iterating through the entire dataframe, the speed will increase dramatically.  Give the following a shot.

```
test_df['result_1'] = (test_df['x']/sea_level_pressure)
test_df['result_1'] = test_df['result']**0.190284
test_df['result_1'] = (1 - test_df['result'])*145366.45

test_df['result_2'] = 3.28084*((np.log(test_df['x']/sea_level_pressure)*test_df['y'])/(-1*(9.80665*0.0289644/8.31447)))

test_df['final_result'] = np.where(pd.isnull(test_df['y']), test_df['result_1'], test_df['result_2'])
```

Comment: Thanks - Your hunch is correct, this would work too.